# chef recipe using application and supervisor_service

Tags: chef-infra

I've been trying to get the following cookbook recipe running - it uses the opscode application and supervisor cookbooks to install things.

The problem is that I would like to not have to always run the supervisor and pip install bits, when I've changed things around to use the commented out lines in the code sample the notifications never get executed.  They should be deferred until after the recipe is run, but are lost.

In the case that the commented lines are removed, the action on the "supervisor_service" is `action :nothing`.

```
application "testing" do
  repository "git@github.com:..."
  path "/opt/somewhere/testing"

  revision "master"
  notifies :run, "execute[pip-ingestion]", :immediately
  #notifies :enable, "supervisor_service[s3batcher]"
  #notifies :restart, "supervisor_service[s3batcher]"

  deploy_key <<EOF
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
....
EOF
end

execute "pip-ingestion" do
  command "pip install -r #{root}/requirements.txt"
  action :run
end

supervisor_service "s3batcher" do
    command "python #{root}/manage.py batch_s3 --settings=#{root}/settings.yaml"
    process_name "s3batcher-%(process_num)s"
    action [:enable, :restart]
    autostart true
    user "root"
    numprocs 1
end
```